# Getting PLS-00103 error while trying to write procedure in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql

First off, if this code is absolutely butchered sorry. I am having trouble with some code for my database programming class. The point of the code is to make it so that if the last letter of a course name is in a certain range, it will automatically change the grades of everyone enrolled in that class to a certain grade. I put the code together essentially trying to substitute the relevant column names based off of an assignment I did on triggers as well as a very basic procedure the professor uploaded. When I run it I get a host of PLS-00103 errors stating "Encountered the symbol '([I get one for each of these] course/section/grades/if)' when expecting one of the following: :=;..." Between not being a programming major and losing a week of lecture due to COVID-19 I'm just stumped. Thank you for taking the time to look at it, and sorry again if it's riddled with mistakes. The code looks like:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE grading AS 
begin 
DECLARE
    CURSOR grading_cursor
    IS SELECT student.student_id,
                course.course_name,
                section.section_id,
                grades.grade
       FROM student
    JOIN grades
    ON student.student_id   = grades.student_id
    JOIN section
    ON grades.section_id   = section.section_id
    JOIN course
    ON section.course_id   = course.course_id;

mycoursename VARCHAR(20) course.course_name%type;
    mySectionID number(10) section.section_id%type;
    myGrade varchar(20) grades.grade%type;

begin    

    open grading_cursor;
    loop
        fetch grading_cursor 
        into myFirstName, myLastName,myCourseName, mySectionID, myGrade
        if myCourseName is between '%a' and '%f' then
        then myGrade = 'A'
        elsif myCourseName is between '%g' and '%k' then
        then myGrade = 'B'
        elsif myCourseName is between '%l' and '%p' then
        then myGrade = 'C'
        elsif myCourseName is between '%q' and '%t' then
        then myGrade = 'D'
        elsif myCourseName is between '%u' and 'z' then
        then myGrade = 'E'
        EXIT WHEN grading_cursor%notfound; 
        end loop; 
    close grading_cursor;
end;

end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you wrote would compile if it looked as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE grading
AS
   CURSOR grading_cursor
   IS
      SELECT student.student_id,
             course.course_name,
             section.section_id,
             grades.grade
        FROM student
             JOIN grades ON student.student_id = grades.student_id
             JOIN section ON grades.section_id = section.section_id
             JOIN course ON section.course_id = course.course_id;

   mystudent_id  student.student_id%TYPE;
   mycoursename  course.course_name%TYPE;
   mySectionID   section.section_id%TYPE;
   myGrade       grades.grade%TYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN grading_cursor;

   LOOP
      FETCH grading_cursor
         INTO mystudentid,
              myCourseName,
              mySectionID,
              myGrade;

      EXIT WHEN grading_cursor%NOTFOUND;

      IF myCourseName BETWEEN '%a' AND '%f'
      THEN
         myGrade := 'A';
      ELSIF myCourseName BETWEEN '%g' AND '%k'
      THEN
         myGrade := 'B';
      ELSIF myCourseName BETWEEN '%l' AND '%p'
      THEN
         myGrade := 'C';
      ELSIF myCourseName BETWEEN '%q' AND '%t'
      THEN
         myGrade := 'D';
      ELSIF myCourseName BETWEEN '%u' AND 'z'
      THEN
         myGrade := 'E';
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE grading_cursor;
END;
/
```

What you did wrong was

- named PL/SQL procedures don't have `DECLARE` keyword
- variables that *inherit* datataype from a column can't have *explicitly* named datatype
- if cursor contains some set of columns, you can't fetch it into another (undeclared) set of variables (e.g. you aren't selecting first nor last name, but still fetch into those undeclared variables), while `student_id` is left out
- `if` requires `end if`
- you doubled all `then`s
- when setting variable's value, you have to use `:=`, not just `=`
- missing semi-colon `;` command terminator in `IF`s

---

**However**, consider this - simpler - option:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE grading
AS
   myGrade  grades.grade%TYPE;
BEGIN
   FOR cur_r
      IN (SELECT LOWER (SUBSTR (course.course_name, -1)) last_char
            FROM student
                 JOIN grades ON student.student_id = grades.student_id
                 JOIN section ON grades.section_id = section.section_id
                 JOIN course ON section.course_id = course.course_id)
   LOOP
      myGrade :=
         CASE
            WHEN cur_r.last_Char BETWEEN 'a' AND 'f' THEN 'A'
            WHEN cur_r.last_Char BETWEEN 'g' AND 'k' THEN 'B'
            WHEN cur_r.last_Char BETWEEN 'l' AND 'p' THEN 'C'
            WHEN cur_r.last_Char BETWEEN 'q' AND 't' THEN 'D'
            WHEN cur_r.last_Char BETWEEN 'u' AND 'z' THEN 'E'
         END;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

- it uses cursor `FOR` loop which is simpler as Oracle does a lot of thing s for you (opening the cursor, fetching from it, paying attention about exiting the loop, closing the cursor)
- I removed columns you don't use
- as you want to check the last character, that's what I really do. Checking whether something is *between*, with a wildcard `%`, isn't the best option

See if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Thank you for showing me a shorter way to do it, I had a feeling I was over complicating it and I obviously was.